# Where in a c# project are 'private accessors' defined

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

After doing a build of a legacy C# application within Visual Studio 2015, the following warning exists:

> This task to create private accessor is deprecated and will be removed
>   in a future version of visual studio.

The warning references a project within the solution which contains only unit tests.

Microsoft dcumentation states:

> Previous versions of Visual Studio, you could use Publicize.exe to
>   specify an internal application programming interfaces (API) and
>   create public counterpart API that you can call in your tests, which
>   would in turn, call into the internal APIs of your product. You could
>   then use code generation to create test stubs and generate code
>   snippet inside that stub.

This functionality was removed in Visual Studio 2012.

Searching the solution, there is no reference in any of the build files to `publicize.exe`.

Where in a C# project would the task to create a private accessor be defined?

Comment: Not sure this is even a build task. Often, the IDE generates the code when you save the main file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should find the accessor in the **.csproj** file of your unit test project.

In Visual studio right click on your test-project and select "**Unload project**".
Then right-click the project again and select "**Edit project-name.csproj**"

The accessor looks something like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Shadow Include="Test References\some-name.accessor" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Why edit the .csproj manually? I right-clicked the .accessor file in Solution Explorer and deleted it (actually I deleted the whole "Test References" folder), and that seemed to work just fine - no more compiler warning.